# synchronizing between send/recv in sockets

Tags: c++, c

I have a server thats sending out data records as strings of varying length(for eg, 79,80,81,82)

I want to be able to receive exactly one record at a time.I've delimited records with a (r) but because I dont know howmany bytes I have to receive, It sometimes merges records and makes it difficult for me to process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two ideas for you:

1. Use XML for the protocol. This way you know exactly when each message ends.
2. Send in the header of each "packet" the packet size, this way you know  how much to read from the socket for this specific packet.

Edit:
Look at this dummy code for (2)

```
int buffer_size;
char* buffer;

read( socket, &buffer_size, sizeof(buffer_size)); 
buffer = (char*) malloc(packet_size);
read( socket, buffer, buffer_size );
// do something
free( buffer) ;
```

EDIT: 
I recommend looking at the comments here, as they note that the contect might not be ready by a simple "read()", you need to keep "read()"ing, until you get the correct buffer size.

Also - you might not need to read the size. Basically you need to look for the ending top level tag of the XML. This can be done by parsing the whole XML, or parlty parsing the XML you get from the stream untill you have 0 nodes "open".

Comment: cant I do this without xml? I can just parse the header myself right?

Comment: There is no guarantee that either `read()` will read exactly what you ask for.  You have to loop around until you get the full packet size, and if you do that then you might as well loop around looking for the end-of-packet delimiter.

Comment: You can also use UDP or SCTP for transmission, because these protocols are message oriented and you always read exactly one, whole message. But remember that UDP doesn't do retransmissions and you could loose some packages.

Comment: @Zuljin, yes and UDP might even be faster if you implement the "connection" manually (ping eveny "x" time). Remember that UDP is not connection oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending your data as a stream?

You can send it as a structure which is easier to parse and retrieve the data from.

```
struct Message
{
  int dataSize;
  char data[256];
};
```

Comment: Please reverse the struct - in practice, the dataSize will be sent first. I know this does not change how this works, but semantically it's clearer.

Comment: @elcuco - Thanks for the tip. Edited accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

You should delimit with null byte. Show us your code, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: It's the least used character, because many applications use it for separation or termination of data segments.

Answer (score 0):

Stream sockets do not natively support an idea of a "record" - the abstraction they provide is that of a continuous stream.

You must implement a layer on top of them to provide "records".  It sounds like you are already part way there, with the end-of-record delimiter.  The pseudo-code to complete it is:

```
create empty buffer;
forever {
    recv data and append to buffer;

    while (buffer contains end-of-record marker) {
        remove first record from buffer and process it;
        move remaining data to beginning of buffer;
    }
}
```